# Alternatives to insert a FAVICON?

Tags: html, web, favicon

I have a problem with the advanced website manager that I am currently using, and that is that it does not allow me access to the HEAD tag, therefore I cannot set a **FAVICON** on the website. I would like to know if there are other alternatives to insert a favicon on the website without changing the HEAD code. The website lacks the appropriate tag to insert a favicon.

*I know it can be a little crazy, but thanks anyway...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to insert a `<link rel="favicon">` by adding a short javascript just before the closing body tag (`</body>`):

```
<script>
let faviconLink = document.createElement('link');

faviconLink.setAttribute('rel', 'favicon');
faviconLink.setAttribute('href', '/path/to/favicon.svg');
faviconLink.setAttribute('type', 'image/svg+xml');

document.head.appendChild(faviconLink);
</script>
```

The example above uses an **SVG** favicon, but you can just as easily use another image format with another MIME type:

- **PNG:** `type="image/png"`
- **GIF:** `type="image/gif"`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a favicon.ico file to the root directory, browsers will still check for it even if it’s not defined in the `<head>`.

BTW, this is a great site for generating all the various app icons and associated code https://realfavicongenerator.net